# textFieldDidEndEditing vs didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the later not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a view with a `UITextField` and a `UITableView`. While the user is entering text I want the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to be called, unfortunately it isn't. It seems that the focus of the textfield prevents the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to be called.

The first solution I found would be to create a gesture recognizer and check if the event coordinates are inside the table, and then check in which row. But I would like to make a simpler solution, I'm probably missing something.

Edit: the textfield is not inside the cell, is outside the table, you are suggesting answers as if it is inside the cell.

Comment: A little trick, would be in the UITextFieldDelegate (In `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`?) method get the superview of the UITextField until you get the cell (depending on how do manage the custom cell), and call yourself `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: pls add some relevant code you tried.

Comment: The question is not enough clear: the textfield is not inside the cell, is outside the table

Comment: Hello @AR89, are you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is called, you can get the cell row, then use it however you need to:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let currentCell = textField.superview!.superview! // Get the cell
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(currentCell)
    let currentRow = (indexPath?.row)! // Get the row of that cell
}
```

Comment: the textfield is not inside the cell, is outside the table

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRow, set the tag of the UITextField to the indexPath.row. Now, when your textfield begins editing, you'll have the row of the indexpath, and can fetch the cellForRow if needed. Put your "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" function logic in a separate function and call that new function from both didSelect and beginsEditing.

Comment: Setting the tag to the `indexPath.row` only works if you have one section and the rows are fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Write  code inside  cellForRowAIndexPath method of uitableview.that prevent from didSelectForRowAtIndexPath cslled method.

tableview.selectiostyle  = UItableviewSelectionStayle.None